# Creating a blended dataset/transitioning from one predictive model to another

Tags: predictive-models

I'm working with two different models right now using a variable X as an input. One of the models is said to be applicable for values of X less than A, and one is said to be applicable for values of X greater than A. However, around A, there is substantial discrepancy in the model outputs, which creates a discontinuity in my work if I simply transition from one model to the other at A.

I'm sure there's a way to create a blended data set or some kind of weighting function to address the region surrounding A, but I have very little statistics background, and haven't been able find any information on how to effectively blend my output data within that region. I found a useful paper that suggests creating a weighted average to combine sets of observations based on an effective dataset, but that requires that some of the observations are common to both sets. In this case, while the inputs may be common to both sets, the outputs are not.

Any insight you can offer would be very much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Please explain further, why you need the functions to be blended. I guess, there is a good reason for each of the predictive models and in comparison little chance of finding equally good reasons for any "mixture to blend" the models. Of course you could just gradually compute a weighed mean of both predictions, but that would include influence of each predictive model in a range, where another modell is said to be better. Therefore you should have good reasons for smoothing/blending.

Comment: The motivation for blending is to avoid the discontinuity at the cross over point. I'm running simulations over a wide range, including values well below and well above that cross over point. If I don't find a way to transition smoothly from one model to the next, I'm concerned that my outputs will reflect the discontinuity. I considered the weighted mean approach, but I'm wondering if there's a more appropriate method. Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: There is a range of X where the appropriate model is contested-- I'm essentially trying to blend the models over that range. Sorry if I was not clear about that from the beginning